# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.spi.ConnectorProvider

Tags: java, docusignapi, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to use Docusign to sign a single document with one recipient through my web app.
I started getting this error : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.spi.ConnectorProvider. I already have the org.glassfish.jersey.client dependency in my pom.xml file.
Java code:

```
package com.uniquedeveloper.registration;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.docusign.esign.api.EnvelopesApi;
import com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient;
import com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException;
import com.docusign.esign.model.Document;
import com.docusign.esign.model.EnvelopeDefinition;
import com.docusign.esign.model.EnvelopeSummary;
import com.docusign.esign.model.Recipients;
import com.docusign.esign.model.SignHere;
import com.docusign.esign.model.Signer;
import com.docusign.esign.model.Tabs;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class test
 */
@WebServlet("/test")
public class test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /*class CreateEnvelope
    {*/
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    // Create the envelope definition
    String accessToken = "eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0.AQoAAAABAAUABwAAfdaxbU_aSAgAAL35v7BP2kgCAEopLU7MQ9VAsqoOKk5pvIYVAAEAAAAYAAEAAAAFAAAADQAkAAAAMmFkY2U4NDItMTVlYi00NzQ0LTk4MDctNWE4MjAyMGNjMzEzIgAkAAAAMmFkY2U4NDItMTVlYi00NzQ0LTk4MDctNWE4MjAyMGNjMzEzMAAA13Rk2E3aSDcADhO7mGzcwECGakKkKBCfzg.n8YBsGs5Ou7GT1tS3-iUlL6DzpaygkpY4Ixiv-0-pNbsJodEBV8qsbAvu22ydV8uEVb1od3TfE1HvKM8pQ2jr4ZY-7uvYxHZQRoPZ5IRBnrTiZR-zkb3iIEBKollEvnBFicW4gnEL-kwrb-eVRW9dEDZIuMLY4PREzJtx7EoRFfJKIARQCgCaOhVdeqLKBjF3BzJawtP5nyohWhX9_z7fejW9kFm_gkO16cDmHQnsRq0KDP3s7UL0yiDUsWtfdlZTB-MXbSN-Vg9Wm50rULuCyMry4QdLNE6Mop0tmUYEbL-Zfi69bEMJGHvxJbb1hJ06NKQNqo3bArjxsrAzjMm2g";
    String accountId = "16501888";
    

    // Call DocuSign to create the envelope
    ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("http://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
    apiClient.addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

    EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
    EnvelopeDefinition envelope = makeEnvelope(request.getParameter("recipientem"), request.getParameter("recipientname"),request.getParameter("file_upload"));
    try {
        EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, envelope);

        String envelopeId = envelopeSummary.getEnvelopeId();
        System.out.println("Envelope ID = "+envelopeId);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

    private  EnvelopeDefinition makeEnvelope(String signerEmail, String signerName, String upload) {
        // Create a signer recipient to sign the document, identified by name and email
        // We set the clientUserId to enable embedded signing for the recipient
        Signer signer = new Signer();
        signer.setEmail(signerEmail);
        signer.setName(signerName);
        // signer.clientUserId("1000"); # will not receive docuSign email to sign if client user id is present
        signer.recipientId("1");

        SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
        signHere.setAnchorString("/sn1/");
        signHere.setAnchorUnits("pixels");
        signHere.setAnchorYOffset("20");
        signHere.setAnchorXOffset("10");

        Tabs signerTabs = new Tabs();
        signerTabs.setSignHereTabs(Arrays.asList(signHere));

        // Add the recipient to the envelope object
        Recipients recipients = new Recipients();
        recipients.setSigners(Arrays.asList(signer));

        EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
        envelopeDefinition.setEmailSubject("Please sign this document");
        envelopeDefinition.setRecipients(recipients);
       
        Path path = Paths.get("uf");
        
        byte[] data = null;
        try {
            data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        Document document = new Document();
        document.setDocumentBase64(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data));
        document.setName("Hello Doc");
        document.setFileExtension("pdf");
        document.setDocumentId("3");

        envelopeDefinition.setDocuments(Arrays.asList(document));
        // Request that the envelope be sent by setting |status| to "sent".
        // To request that the envelope be created as a draft, set to "created"
        envelopeDefinition.setStatus("sent");

        return envelopeDefinition;
    }
}
```

My pom.xml file :

```
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Trial1</groupId>
  <artifactId>Trial1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>15</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.docusign</groupId>
  <artifactId>docusign-esign-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.19.0</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0-M3</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

And finally the error trace :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.spi.ConnectorProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    at com.uniquedeveloper.registration.test.doPost(test.java:44)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Here is the code at test.java 44
`ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("http://demo.docusign.net/restapi");`

PLease help as this is for an internship thank youuuu !!!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
<artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
<version>3.0.2.Final</version>
```